# Golang unbuffered channel size?

Tags: go

Here is an example of book go in action https://github.com/goinaction/code/blob/master/chapter2/sample/search/search.go

```
    // Launch a goroutine to monitor when all the work is done.
    go func() {
        // Wait for everything to be processed.
        waitGroup.Wait()

        // Close the channel to signal to the Display
        // function that we can exit the program.
        close(results)
    }()

    // Start displaying results as they are available and
    // return after the final result is displayed.
    Display(results)
```

If I move waitGroup.Wait() and close(results) out of the goroutine function, program is blocked because the results in channel are not read yet, and it blocks at writing other more result into channel after it gets to a "size". But if I use a big size buffered channel:

```
results := make(chan *Result, 100)
```

program recovers back to normal. It seems that channel is blocked due to size limit and can not write more before consuming it. Is there a size limit for unbeffered channel ? why it writes a few messages into channel and decreases WaitGroup counter a little, then blocks itself at there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [unbuffered channel](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) by definition doesn't have a buffer size. Sending blocks if there is something to read. Please take the [go tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) to familiarize yourself.

The reason the code above blocks is that you are waiting for the WaitGroup counter to reach zero. I assume this is done after the goroutines (the ones you don't show) are done writing to the channel. One of them writes, but all others are blocking. `Display` is supposed to read from the channel (you also don't show that code), but never gets called. This means that nothing is ever consuming from the channel.

Changing to a size 100 channel is only a temporary workaround. If you send more than 100 elements to the channel, it will still block as nothing is reading from it.

Comment: code write message into channel https://github.com/goinaction/code/blob/master/chapter2/sample/search/match.go#L29 Display function https://github.com/goinaction/code/blob/master/chapter2/sample/search/match.go#L37 one thing I don't understand is that it write a few message into channel and WriteGroup counter decreased. Shouldn't it stop after write first message and only decrease by 1 ?

Comment: Yes, I saw that by following the link. It should really have been in the question though.

Comment: Are you sure there are things written to the channel? How do you know, you don't have anything to read/print the elements. If there are no results, or an error, it won't write anything and just exit, decreasing the counter. I suspect that if you log the entries just after `results <- result`, you'll see exactly one.

Comment: I put an output messages after WaitGroup.Done() in https://github.com/goinaction/code/blob/master/chapter2/sample/search/search.go#L40 Is that correct behavior to see like almost 10 output message before suspending ? EDIT : If it won't write and exit, why it only shows 10, but not the number of the gorouinte in loop ?

Comment: You may be seeing `WaitGroup.Done()` called 10 times, but `Match` can exit without writing anything to the channel.

Comment: adding an extra log.Printf("after write") after results <- result. There is zero message in terminal

Comment: If your `Printf` inside or outside the `range` loop? If it's outside, there may be more than one result being sent and only the first one succeeds, blocking on the second one. Or it could just be log buffering or output to non-stdout.

Answer (score 2):

Buffer size means is a number of elements you can send to it without blocking it. By default, it's 0 (unbuffered channel), so if you sending something to channel its blocking till the moment channel will be read by goroutine. When you making a size of 100 for channel, the channel will be blocked at the 100th message.

Answer (score 0):

Capacity (number of elements what can be stored in a channel) for unbuffered channel is zero. So it gets blocked right now when one goroutine starts to write to it. And unlocks when another goroutine would read that message from it.

When you make it buffered - that means all your messages (at least in this case 100 is enough) are put into the buffer. And no need to wait until some another goroutine will read them from channel

Why you can pass several messages in this case? That means other process is reading them.

Comment: I was wrong, not passing several messages. it tried to write into channel and blocks. But I still see many waitGroup.Done() is called which means counter is decreased.